# Ruby on rails table not saving an additional object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a has_many :active_posts table in my User model. I'm fairly confident that it is set up correctly. However, when I try to add an already existing object to the table, it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated!

model user.rb

```
  def addpost(other_post)
    active_posts << other_post
  end
```

the view _feed.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @training_post, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}, url: confirm_training_post_path(post), method: :patch do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.submit "Confirm", class: "btn-primary btn-xs form-control" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

the controller posts_controller.rb

```
def confirm     
  @post = Post.find_by(id: params[:id])
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @post.toggle!(:confirm)
  @post.update_attribute(:propreceived, active_post_params[:propreceived])
  current_user.addpost(@post)
  current_user.deletepassivepost(@post)
  redirect_to root_url

end
```

Comment: which is the other attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're not saving the user's active_posts, instead just adding it to the collection. You need to save the user's active_posts somehow.

Assuming `active_posts` has a schema of `user_id` and `post_id`:

```
user.rb

def add_post(post)
  self.active_posts.create(:post => post)
end
```

Comment: thanks! I had to configure my form_for to actually build another active_post instead of just adding it to the collection.